# Matplotlib save individual "ims" (animation parts) as image

Tags: python, matplotlib

Part of why I can't find the solution is probably that I don't know what `ims` are called; they're called `lines.Line2D` when printed...

Say I have this boring animation ([documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.1/examples/animation/basic_example.html)):

```
x = linspace(0, 2, 100)
f = lambda x: 2**x
fig, ax = subplots()
ims = []
for delta in range(15):
    ims.append([
        ax.plot(x, f(x) + delta, c = 'r')[0], 
        ax.plot(x, (f(x) + delta)**2, c = 'b')[0]
    ])
im_ani = ArtistAnimation(fig, ims)
show()
```

Now I want to save the second line from a specific frame, e.g. `ims[-1][1]` as an image. How might I do that?

Failing that, how might I save a specific frame?

(I want to do it without creating the plots twice, which I am aware is a fallback solution.)

Comment: What do you mean by 'now I want to save the second line from a specific frame, e.g. ims[-1][1] as an image.'  Do you want _just_ the line or do you want the frame with only the second line?

Comment: @tcaswell Second one, so the full image I would have gotten had I called `ax.plot(x, (f(x) + delta)**2, c = 'b')` for delta=15. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that `ArtistAnimation` works is by having a list of artists and then controlling the visibility of them to create the animation.  To get a singe frame with just one of the artists just have to fake up that behavior.

```
x = linspace(0, 2, 100)
f = lambda x: 2**x
fig, ax = subplots()
ims = []
for delta in range(15):
    ims.append(list(ax.plot(x, f(x) + delta, c='r') +  
                    ax.plot(x, (f(x) + delta)**2, c='b'))
    )
im_ani = ArtistAnimation(fig, ims)
show()
```

First you have to stop the animation.

```
del im_ani # this _should_ stop the animation by letting the gc do it's job
```

or just closing the figure should work.

A helper function something like:

```
def save_single_frame(fig, arts, frame_number, artist_number=-1):
    # make sure everything is hidden
    for frame_arts in arts:
        for art in frame_arts:
            art.set_visible(False)
    # make the one artist we want visible
    arts[frame_number][artist_number].set_visible(True)
    fig.savefig("frame_{}.png".format(frame_number))
```

and call the function

```
save_single_frame(fig, ims, 5)  # this should save the animation for you
```